# Display div if a specific select option value is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one question regardinh PHP+HTML+Java. I need to display a div with textarea only when a value if text required is 1, ex: **[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psIgx.jpg)**

[image]

If the 3 columns are 1, then the div show to put some text, how can I do this with HTML and Java? I already try to use this without success:

**SCRIPT**

```js
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
        if(admOptionValue == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
<option value="1">Jay</option>
<option value="4">Sam</option>
<option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
admin selected
</div>
```

The problem is that the Value must be the column 1 from my table, and I need the DIV to show or not according to value in my column 3.

How can I do this?

Sincerely,
Marcos Fernandes

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Sorry Nick, you are right. My mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onchange

```
function admSelectCheck() { 
  var x = document.getElementById("getFname").value;
  if(x == 0) {
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

upd:
html

```
<style>
 .thediv { display: none; } 
</style>
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck()">
  <option value="1">Vendor will send Credit Note (requires text)</option>
  <option value="2">Return to supplier </option>
  <option value="3">Accept diversion (requires text)</option>
</select>
<div id="1" class="thediv">1</div>
<div id="2" class="thediv">2</div>
<div id="3" class="thediv">3</div>
```

and js

```
function admSelectCheck() {
 var selectedValue = document.getElementById("getFname").value;
 var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("thediv");
 for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
   divs[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 document.getElementById(selectedValue).style.display = "block";
}
```

If you want to show text of the selected option;

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck()">
  <option value="1">Vendor will send Credit Note (requires text)</option>
  <option value="2">Return to supplier </option>
  <option value="3">Accept diversion (requires text)</option>
</select>
<div id="TextGoesHere">default text</div>

  function admSelectCheck() {
   //get select element by id
   var select = document.getElementById("getFname");
   // get selected option value
   var value = select.value;
   // get selected option text
   var optionText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
   // replace html of the div to the text of selected option
   document.getElementById("TextGoesHere").innerHTML = optionText;
   //or for a specific cases
   if(value == 3) {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").innerHTML = 'the value is 3';
   }
```

}

Comment: This show always the infor insido <p>..</p>. I just what to show this when id=1. And i can have one ore more id=1 inside my <select>/<option>

Comment: see edit, like this you will be able to show whatever div depending on your selected value, also its bad idea having not unique ids

Comment: The thing is that the value='' i use to save by php to database. The ID will be the other value that if it is 1 than the DIV with TextArea appears to put some description. I need to do this dynamically, not creating one div per each option.

Comment: So you just get text from the selected option and add to the div.

Comment: Ok, and how can i do that? Can you help me, please?

Comment: Manchary Manchaary, i work with your code, but have one question. I already have class defined for the div, this is Bootstrap theme. Is any other option??

Comment: ...`a)` Do you want to just show the text of selected option inside of a div `b)` Do you want to show the text of the div when specific option is selected, please choose what you want, because im confused

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all your help. I did with diferent DIV with PHP help and some IF clauses.

Answer (score 0):

try following code should help you

```
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
  <option value="1">Jay</option>
  <option value="4">Sam</option>
  <option id="admOption" value="0">Admin</option>
</select>
<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
  admin selected
</div>
<script>
  function admSelectCheck(obj)
  {
    var nameSelect = obj.value;
    console.log(nameSelect);
    if(nameSelect){
      admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
      if(admOptionValue == nameSelect){
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zsv70v2q/

Comment: Hi i have one other <option> with id="admOption", this code only show div for the first <option> with id="admOption" :(

Comment: Ok, so how can i do ?

Comment: you can define div ids that match to the values of the options, by selecting option you show specific div(see my answer)...or you can have only one div, that will show text of the selected option, where you can conditionaly show text depending on what option is selected...Because you have got TWO same ids it shows you the last one

Comment: So, how can i do what i whant? I have 3 values, ID, description and option 2. The option 2 (if it = 1) determine if the DIV our TextArea box show or not, can be TextArea enable/disable, can you help me?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all your help. I did with diferent DIV with PHP help and some IF clauses.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question requires work with php file so when you select and assign your value get information from your table to know the value of the third column with that ID and according to it you determine that div will be display block or none.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all your help. I did with diferent DIV with PHP help and some IF clauses.